# nls fitting for each row + saving coef & SSE values in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, exponential, stat, nls

I have a dataframe including 520 individual identification #s and their frequency count over 10 bin/indices. I want to fit nls() for each of them & save their coef and r^2 values each in a new column.

```
structure(list(User.ID = c("37593", "38643", "49433", "60403", 
"70923"), V1 = c(9L, 3L, 4L, 80L, 19L), V2 = c(10L, 0L, 29L, 
113L, 21L), V3 = c(5L, 2L, 17L, 77L, 7L), V4 = c(2L, 2L, 16L, 
47L, 4L), V5 = c(2L, 10L, 16L, 40L, 1L), V6 = c(4L, 0L, 9L, 22L, 
1L), V7 = c(6L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 0L), V8 = c(2L, 17L, 16L, 24L, 2L
), V9 = c(3L, 20L, 7L, 30L, 0L), V10 = c(2L, 11L, 5L, 11L, 2L
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I like to perform nls() or fit exponential for each row, meaning each user. I also want to add three columns to the existing dataframe for A, k, and SSE each to record their values for each user/each row.

```
FreqBin=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
for (i in 1:nrow(Mfrq.df.2)){
  eaUser=Mfrq.df.2[i,2:11]
  ExpFit[i]=nls(eaUser[i]~A*exp(k*FreqBin), start=c(A=1, k=0.01))
}
```

This code is what I tried, but I got this error.

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~eaUser + i + FreqBin) : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'eaUser'
```

Any code suggestion that I should try?

Comment: Can you please post your data sample in a textual format (e.g. cut-and-paste values as a code block, or use `dput()`) ?

Comment: The 4th row has an issue with nls. Also whats the reason for R^2 in an exponential model?

Comment: There is no R^2 in nls. Probably you mean the SSE?

Comment: @onyambu Thanks for pointing it out. Did some search and understood your point.

Comment: @BenBolker Did you find the dput() helpful?

Comment: Haven't gotten around to it (I have a day job ...)

Answer (score 0):

The forth person causes an issue, here is the nls code:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1)%>%
  group_by(User.ID)%>%
  mutate(bins = 1:10)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!=4)%>%
  summarise(broom::tidy(nls(value~A*exp(k*bins),cur_data(), start=c(A=1, k=0.01))))




   User.ID term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
     <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1   37593 A      10.9       2.41       4.51  0.00197
 2   37593 k      -0.190     0.0612    -3.10  0.0146 
 3   38643 A       1.74      1.39       1.25  0.247  
 4   38643 k       0.229     0.0932     2.46  0.0395 
 5   49433 A      18.6       6.20       3.00  0.0170 
 6   49433 k      -0.0713    0.0647    -1.10  0.302  
 7   70923 A      35.0       7.34       4.77  0.00141
 8   70923 k      -0.465     0.108     -4.32  0.00254
 9   85363 A       2.48      1.54       1.61  0.147  
10   85363 k       0.0614    0.0882     0.696 0.506
```

You can compare the results by running just one nls:

```
nls(value~A*exp(k*bins), data.frame(value=unlist(df[1,-1]), bins = 1:10), c(A=1, k=0.01))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: value ~ A * exp(k * bins)
   data: data.frame(value = unlist(df[1, -1]), bins = 1:10)
      A       k 
10.8628 -0.1901 
 residual sum-of-squares: 33.66

Number of iterations to convergence: 6 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.793e-06
```

Comment: What is value here? I would also like to add columns A & k to the end of my data sample. Thanks

Comment: @MK25 value is the row of each user\

Comment: It didn't work. Still had errors & I don't quite understand the solution & how to create the columns. But much appreciated

Comment: @MK25 probably because you are using a dataframe different from the one I used. You havent even stated what your errors are, so not easy to help

Comment: I tried the code again I managed to run it. But the loop is not the most efficient. Like your fourth row, it is showing error for some group #. I ran nls() for them individually & it worked. So this is error num 1. + I am still not sure how to add three columns in my existing data and save the stated values in them. The solution seems is a bit distanced from what I was looking for.

Comment: `Mfrq.df.2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-1)%>%
  group_by(User.ID)%>%
  mutate(Freqbins = 1:10)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 6)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 7)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 57)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 58)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 62)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 63)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 77)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 79)%>%
  filter(cur_group_id()!= 84)%>%
  summarise(broom::tidy(nls(value~A*exp(k*Freqbins),cur_data(), start=c(A=1, k=0.01))))` I have 520 users & need information on them & can't filter them all out.

Comment: @MK25 you claim that using the data from the 4th user runs, but that is not the case. ie `nls(value~A*exp(k*bins), data.frame(value=unlist(df[4,-1]), bins = 1:10), c(A=1, k=0.01))` does not work. It produces an error. You cannot use it. You can write a function with try catch to give you NA in this case